# Integrate $\int_{C}\frac{\tan z}{z^2}dz$, where $C$ is the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to integrate $$\int_{C}\frac{\tan z}{z^2}dz$$ over the unit circle.
I can't use the Cauchy formula as there is a problem at 0, so how would I go about this?

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral formula for the derivatives?

Comment: @Surb You are perfectly right... I rewrite my comment...

Comment: @MartinR yeah I do. So if I could use that, I'd set f(z) as tan and z_0 = 0?

Comment: Use the Taylor expansion of $\tan z$. The coefficient of $z$ will become the coefficient of 1/z, i.e. the residue in $0$.

Comment: @fighting_fish: Exactly. The result would be $2\pi i f'(0)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(0)=1$ and $f(z)=\frac {\tan z} z$ for $z \neq 0$. Then $f$ is analytic (because $\frac {\tan z} z \to 1$ as $z \to 0$) and the given integral is $\int_C \frac {f(z)} z dz=2\pi if(0)=2\pi i$.

Comment: (+1) I commented this very point before I read your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply Cauchy's integral formula for the derivative to $f(z) = \tan z$ (which is holomophic in a neighborhood of the unit disk):
$$
 \int_C \frac{\tan(z)}{z^2}\, dz = 2 \pi i f'(0) = 2 \pi i.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As a generalization of the above answers(Which I think all of them are correct). You can look for the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20complex%20analysis%2C%20a%20discipline,and%20infinite%20series%20as%20well.).

Using the residue Theorem for the function $\frac{\tan z}{z^{2}}$. As the curve $C$ here is parametrized as follows(I assume.) $C: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $C(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. So the winding number of $C$ is $1$. And as $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has a pole of order $2$ in $0$ and no where else inside the $C$. And also $\tan z$ has no poles inside the $C$ we have that :
$$ \int_{C} \frac{\tan z}{z^{2}}dz = 2\pi i \hspace{2mm}\text{Res}(\frac{\tan z}{z^2}, 0)$$
here $\text{Res}(\frac{\tan z}{z^2},0)$  eqauls to $\tan^{\prime}(0)$.